# C# Get repeating XML tags into DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, sqlbulkcopy

I have an XML file that I'm trying to parse and save to a database in a C# program. For most of the elements in this file, I have been able to use SqlBulkCopy because these elements are arranged well with either unique names for child tags or attributes on the root node. However, I have one element that has child elements with repeating tag names (just "tag") but uses attribute names to describe what it is. I have not been able to save this with SqlBulkCopy, which I would prefer since this file can be as large as 500MB and the SqlBulkCopy class is much faster. I tried the code below, but I can see by debugging that the ds.Tables collection is separating hostproperties and tag. I'm guessing this is just how the ReadXml method works. What would be the easiest way that I could get these tags into a datatable object that has the individual attributes as columns so that I could use SqlBulkCopy?

**Current C# Code**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.ReadXml(file.InputStream);

DataTable hostItems = ds.Tables["host"];
conn.Open();

using (SqlBulkCopy sb = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    sb.DestinationTableName = "HOSTS";
    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("host-ip", "HOST_IP");
    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("host-name", "NAME");
    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("system-type", "SSH_FINGERPRINT");
    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("os", "OS");
    sb.WriteToServer(hostItems);
 }
```

**XML File**

```
<host>
    <tag name="host-ip">192.168.200.8</tag>
    <tag name="host-name">someserver.mydomain.com</tag>
    <tag name="system-type">webserver</tag>
    <tag name="os">WindowsServer2019</tag>
</host>
...
<host>
    <tag name="host-ip">192.168.200.9</tag>
    <tag name="host-name">someserver2.mydomain.com</tag>
    <tag name="system-type">webserver</tag>
    <tag name="os">WindowsServer2019</tag>
    <tag name="attributeFirstOneDidntHave">Some nonsense</tag>
</host>
```

**Edit**

I failed to mention that not all of the hosts have the same amount of tags. I have updated the XML example to illustrate this.

Comment: XML is a relational structure and that's why you are getting a table for `host` and a table for `tag`. Host is seen as an 'entity' with related tag 'entities'.

Comment: One option could be to flatten the host/tag relationship into a new dataset and pass that to your bulk copy method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With huge xml files you need to use XmlReader, otherwise, you will get an out of memory error.  Below the code uses a combination of xmlreader and xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            long count = 0;
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "host")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("host");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement host = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    if (++count == 1)
                    {
                        foreach (XElement tag in host.Elements("tag"))
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add((string)tag.Attribute("name"),typeof(string));
                        }
                    }
                    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
                    foreach (XElement tag in host.Elements("tag"))
                    {
                        row[(string)tag.Attribute("name")] = (string)tag;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction and seems to have around the same efficiency. However, one question: how would I read multiple nodes in one pass using this? Say I was looking for this host node and two other nodes on different levels (say, hardware and installedSoftware)? Would I use something other than ReadToFollowing?

Comment: I've tried it a couple of times and it becomes messy.  I had a huge SVG file to parse and used ReadToFollowing to go between different nodes.  I think the best way is just to use a common parent.